# Multiple Column Order MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to order by code in one of my quiz application api. I want result sort by score and time of user. I have column like score and time. score contain user's score and time contains time user have took for finish quiz. I want sort them in result as highest score + lowest time will be first. current my code for it is like below

```
SELECT * FROM contest_score order by score desc, time ASC
```

This code working but if there multiple user have same score then its showing only one user which have lowest time. What should I correct for get result ?

For example if there 3 user have score and time like below

```
user1 : score= 100, time =5.0
user2 : score = 98 time = 6.0
user3 : score = 100 time = 4.5
```

I want arrange user like first= user3, second=user1 and third user2

Thanks

Comment: Is that your actual query? As you've given it, that wouldn't omit any rows.

Comment: yes, I am using same as I have posted...Thanks

Comment: If that is the query, it should sort like you want it to. Are you doing any summing, etc.?

Comment: Then I'm not sure what your problem is. If you have multiple users who have the same score and the same time, it will show alll of them, not only one as you have described.

Comment: Unless you have a where clause or are doing some aggregate function that would require group by, it should work.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Could you please show the table with the column types?

Comment: @Priya : What is the type of the column `score` and `time`?

Comment: @Arion score is int and time is varchar

Comment: @Priya if time is actually the time you might want to change it to double.

Comment: @RMT I think you mean DECIMAL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean you could do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM contest_score 
order by 
   score desc, 
   CAST(time as DECIMAL(9,2)) ASC
```

It is a bit dirty. The better option would be to save it as decimal instead